# C - Search for same values close to each other in an array?

Tags: c

I have an array that contains x elements. I want to search through each element in the array to see if it matches my input value. However, there is a rule: The integer to search for must be in at least two elements of the array AND these elements must either be next to each other, or have maximum one element between each other. So this is what I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int elements;
    int input;
    int i;

    printf("How many elements in the array? ");
    scanf("%d", &elements);

    int array[elements];

    printf("Ok, please input %d integer values: ", elements);

    for(i=0; i < elements; i++)
    {
            scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    printf("Which integer should I search for? ");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    for(i=0; i < elements; i++)
    {
            if((array[i] == input && array[i+1] == input) || (array[i] == input && array[i+2] == input))
            {
                    printf("Match!\n");
                    break;
            }

            else
            {
                    printf("Match not found!\n");
                    break;
            }
    }

    getchar();
    getchar();
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't work like intended, because if there are two elements between the integers I search for, it will still find a match.

Example of how the program should look:

```
Array: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5
Integer to search for: 5
Match found! // 5 and 5 are next to each other

Array: 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5
Integer to search for: 2
Match found! // 2 and 2 has only one element (3) between each other

Array: 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 5
Integer to search for: 2
Match not found! // 2 and 2 has more than one element between each other
```

Comment: If you loop from `0` to `elements-1`, then `array[i+2]` will be out of bounds if `i = elements-1`, same for array[i+1].

Comment: array[i+1] and array[i+2] accesses elements that are not part of your array.

Comment: Your `for` loop always stops at a first iteration.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work either. It's getting so messy that it's hard to understand. Andrey, my for loop is looping through the whole array (as long as a match not is found, but if a match is found there is no reason to keep looping through it)?


`(array[i-1] == input && array[i+1-1] == input) || (array[i-1] == input && array[i+2-1] == input)`

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean, Andrey. I shouldn't have `break;` in the else statement.

Comment: You have `break` in both ways: `if(cond) { break; } else { break; }`

Answer (score 0):

Strange enough.In my `gcc 4.6.3`

it shows

```
How many elements in the array? 6
Ok, please input 6 integer values: 1
2
1
1
2
5
Which integer should I search for? 2
Match not found!
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to improve your loop

```
            for (i = 0; i < elements - 2; i++)
            {
                if ((array[i] == input && array[i + 1] == input) || (array[i] == input && array[i + 2] == input))
                {
                    printf("Match!\n");
                    break;
                }
                else if (i + 1 == elements - 2)
                {
                    if (array[i + 1] == input && array[i + 2] == input)
                    {
                        printf("Match!\n");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        printf("Match not found!\n");
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: the `else` branch still breaks the loop at the first iteration

Comment: @Ingo, didn't realize the else part was only trying to fix the indexing part. Made the changes.

Comment: I have trying to understand but I can't understand why you have the else if statement in the code. And I don't understand why it's `elements -2`.

Comment: @user2928113, effectively i+2 should be less than elements. Otherwise when you do array[i+2] you will be accessing elements not in the scope of your array.Else if statement is to compare the last two elements in your array. You can put some value in the elements(say 5) and trace the flow.